# JavaScript: What's the difference between the approaches

Tags: javascript

If I have the following variable declaration:

```
var person = function () {
    // private properties
    var name, age, address;

    // Return a new object literal with methods
    return {
        // setters
        set_name: function (n) { name = n; },
        set_age: function (n) { age = n; },
        set_address: function (n) { address = n; },

        // we can similarly write getters, if we want to.

        get_details: function () { return name + ":" + age + ":" + address }
    };
}();
```

Now, what's the difference between the following two assignments:

1. `var rajat = person;`
2. `var rajat = person();`

**[Edit]**

I am using "JavaScript: The Good Parts" and this kind of example is on page 42. I figured out that it's a reported errata and the example should not be having a trailing `()` in `person`'s definition. Check out the errata [here](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596517748).

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: person is not a function(…)` when using `var rajat = person();`

Comment: *"Because, the following lines are producing same results for both."* No, they don't; see the comment above for why not.

Comment: I am using "The Good Parts" by D. Crockford and he has used the same approach `person()` in his book.

Comment: Not reproducible. Voting to close.

Comment: The book probably used the function version of `person` on one side and the immediately invoked version in the other.

Comment: Please check out my edit

Answer (score 3):

The 2 statements are not equivalent. As a matter of fact the second will throw a javascript error because you are treating `person` as a function which it is not. The `person` variable is an instance of a class that has the `set_name`, `set_age`, `set_address` and `get_details` methods.

If you have defined `person` as a class and not an instance (notice the missing `()` at the end of the declaration):

```
var person = function () {
    // private properties
    var name, age, address;

    // Return a new object literal with methods
    return {
        // setters
        set_name: function (n) { name = n; },
        set_age: function (n) { age = n; },
        set_address: function (n) { address = n; },

        // we can similarly write getters, if we want to.

        get_details: function () { return name + ":" + age + ":" + address }
    };
};
```

then you could get an instance of it like this:

```
var rajat = person();
```